# GET JournalArticle with Id and its Title

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm developing a select that shows a title of a JA and has its ID as a value.

```
<aui:select label="<%= segment %>" name="<%= segment %>" multiple="true">
        <%
        for (int j = 0; j < articles.size(); j++) {
            String title = articles.get(j).getTitle();
            String idTitle = articles.get(j).getArticleId();
            System.out.println("id : " + idTitle);
        %>
            <aui:option value="<%= idTitle %>">
                <liferay-ui:message key="<%= title %>" />
            </aui:option>
        <%
        }
        %> 
</aui:select>
```

The fact is that I save the selected JA Id's on portlet preferences (when I process the action) and now I want to get the title of that JA with the help of that Id from `init.jsp` to show the selected JA:

```
long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
String jaId = contents[j];
            JournalArticle art = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(groupId, jaId);

            System.out.println("JA : " + art);
            rule += " idContent : " + contents[j] + " with title : " + art.getTitle();
```

The variable content is a collection of the JA id's collected:

```
<%
        for (int j = 0; j < articles.size(); j++) {
            String title = articles.get(j).getTitle();
            String idTitle = articles.get(j).getArticleId();
```

It's a `String[]` of `idTitle`s.

The problem here is that `art.getTitle` returns null. How is that possible?

Comment: what is "contents[j]" here? can you post some more code

Comment: I improved my question, hope that now you could help me! Thanks

Comment: Is the `art` also `null`? And the `themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId()` is the current group, maybe the article has global group.

Comment: This: String jaId = contents[j];
   JournalArticle art = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getLatestArticle(Long.parseLong(jaId)); give me an error:  No JournalArticle exists with the key.

Comment: But it's just the key I retrieved on the view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ttry to store the primaryKey of the article and get it with:

```
JournalArticle art = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(long primaryKey);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the problem is that I was working with id's and It should be with primaryKey...

Comment: Now I have another issue, when I do getTitle() over JA, I get: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><Title language-id="en_US">prova3</Title></root>  Does any way to get only the title, not all the xml??? Thank you another time!

Comment: journalArticle.getTitle(LocaleUtil.getDefault().getLanguage()), but this is another question :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my second question is that:

To solve the parse problem and if you are using LR6.1.X then you have to use locale as the title and content saved in the form of xml on the basis of locale use,

```
LocaleUtil.getDefault();
```

Thanks to all!